# ASP.Net - Fazer Page.UICulture retornar cultura no formato "pt-BR"

Tags: c#, asp.net, culture

Foi definido no **Web.config** o globalization:

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="pt-BR" uiCulture="pt-BR"/>
```

No entanto, quando leio o `Page.UICulture` me retorna **"Português (Brasil)"**, eu quero que retorne o código **"pt-BR"**. Existe algum método de conversão? Fazer **if** não é uma solução que eu gostaria de usar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Encontrei uma solução:

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.Name
```

Essa propriedade me retorna o código do idioma no formato que quero.

Answer (score 1):

Para recuperar o idioma do navegador do usuário utilizo sempre, da seguinte forma:

```
List<string> Idiomas = new List<string>() { "pt-BR", "es-MX", "en-US" };
string cultureInfo;
try
{

    var userLanguages = Request.UserLanguages;
    if (Idiomas.Contains(userLanguages[0]))
    {
        cultureInfo = userLanguages[0];
    }
    else
    {
        cultureInfo = "pt-BR";
    }
}
catch
{
    cultureInfo = "pt-BR";
}
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(cultureInfo);
```

Utilizo assim em minha carga inicial, aqui trabalho com sistemas para 3 países.

Mais uma opção para trabalhar.

Comment: Muito obrigado Alexsandro, sua resposta foi muito útil para outra coisa que eu precisava fazer hehe!